# How to configure expander card RES2SV240 in an Intel Server Board S2600WT?

Tags: raid, sas, intel

So, I'm trying to configure this expander card into my server.

I have an Intel Server Board S2600WT in a R2312WTTYS case, which means I have a backplane in the front with 12 slots, and another backplane in the back holding 2 disks.

Front backplane has 10 disks: slots 0 and 1 holding a SSD, and slots 2-9 holding a SATA disk. These are connected to the expander as instructed [here on page 48 in the PDF](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/s2600wt_config_guide_2_02.pdf), connecting front backplane to first 3 slots in the expander card, and connecting last 2 ports in the expander card to the motherboard's SATA ports 0-3 (motherboard has 2 mini SAS HD ports named the same).

Back backplane holds 2 SSD. These are connected to SATA ports 4 and 5 respectively.

Problem is, system is not recognizing the expander, nor the disks connected to it.

I tried with both RAID controllers in the BIOS: INTEL ESRT2 (LSI+), and INTEL RSTe; but none of them seems to find the card.

I tried connecting only one port of the expander to the motherboard. Also tried disconnecting SATA drives at ports 4 and 5. And also tried changing the order of the connections in the expander.

I have no idea how this should look, or how to go any further. Am I missing something? or is something wrong with my expander card?

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Intel Support, and happens I needed an offBoard RAID Controller.

They gave me a list of [compatible devices](http://ark.intel.com/compare/60284,60283,60287,60286,60289,60288,60281,60280,82030,82029,81863,81864,60285,60282,65856,55793,59674,60279,77347,77346,76067,76065,81146,81147,76066,81278,81277,49596,64080,60290) in order to make thing work.